# How to pass a reference to a variable to a method - not the value of a variable - in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my template I have this:

```
<input @input="myMethod(myVariableName)" />
```

Then I have myMethod

```
myMethod(variablePassed) {
  console.log(variablePassed)
}
```

What I receive is the value of the `"variablePassed"` (of course). But, is there a way for me to see which variable got passed?

Comment: No. A function call is evaluated by first completely evaluating the argument expressions. Once that's done, all that's left of each argument expression is its value.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by knowing the name of the variable?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could do that by passing the variable wrapped inside a literal object `{}` and use `Object.keys(varname)[0]` to get its name and `Object.values(varname)[0]` to get its value:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      name: "john"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    myMethod(variablePassed) {
      
      console.log(Object.keys(variablePassed)[0])
       console.log(Object.values(variablePassed)[0])
      
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
  <input @input="myMethod({name})" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is great. Do you see a way to pass a variable nested in an object? If "name" was an object with nested "firstName" for example?

"name.firstName"

Comment: i didn't understand what you want exactly ?

Comment: If the "name" variable was an object >> name: { first: "john", last: "Jackson" } and you wanted to pass "name.first" to the method.

Comment: ah ok in this case you couldn't

Comment: no problem. But your example above with a simple variable worked fine.

Comment: could you explain more your use case? i hope that i could help you